# ヘルプセンターの「新規ユーザーの制限の解除」を改善したい

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの [新規ユーザーの制限の解除](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) において、いくつか修正したい箇所があります。

---

#### "リンクを追加する方法" の説明

投稿にリンクを含める方法についての説明がされていますが、日本語版では以下のように Markdown でのレンダリングがされた後の結果が表示されています。

**日本語版での表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし本来なら「どのように入力すればよいか」の説明なはずなので、Markdown でのレンダリング前の
**素の文字列** が表示されるべきだと思います。

**英語語版での表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

#### (ついでに) 細かな文言の修正

"匿名インターネットからの参加" とありますが、ここは "匿名ユーザーからの参加" だと思います。
(原文では "from anonymous internet users" となってます)
匿名インターネットだと、プロキシやTorを使ったアクセスのような印象になってしまう気がします。

Answer (score 4):

ヘルプ センター > 権限
[新規ユーザーの制限の解除](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) のドラフトです。どうぞ直接ご編集くださいませ m_ _m。

---

### 新規ユーザーの制限の解除

#### 新規ユーザーの制限とは？

新規ユーザーは以下のことができません。

- 一度に 2 件を超えるハイパーリンクを投稿する (投稿またはユーザー プロフィールで)
- 保護済みの質問に回答を寄せる
- 質問や回答を非常に高頻度で行う

#### 新規ユーザーに制限があるのはなぜですか？

匿名ユーザーからの参加を許可しているため、まれなことですが悪意のあるユーザーやスパマーのような匿名ユーザーが他のユーザーの体験を損なわないことを保証するための予防策が必要です。

新規ユーザーに対してサンドボックス アプローチをとらなければならないのは残念ですが、質問または回答に賛成票が数票集まれば、すぐにそこから昇進できます！

#### 保護済みの質問とは？

サイト上の投稿の多い質問は、新規ユーザーからの「ありがとうございました！」、「私も！」やスパムの回答を防ぐために保護されることがあります。

保護済みの質問に回答するためには、信用度を 10 点獲得する必要があります。関連付けボーナスはカウントされません。

#### 投稿にリンクを追加する方法は？

投稿の書式設定には Markdown を使用するので、様々な方法でリンクを追加できます。

- ベア URL `https://example.com`
- HTML `<a href="https://example.com">example link</a>`
- Markdown `[example link](https://example.com)`
- エディタのツールバーボタン[image: リンク挿入ツールバー ボタン]

---