# ヘルプセンターの「どこでもコメント」で、意図せずMarkdownが反映されている

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの [どこでもコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) における説明が、[関連のメタ投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3335) と同じように Markdown が反映された状態で表示されてしまっています。

---

**日本語版での表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**英語版での表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

現時点では Markdown が反映されない形で表示されていました。どこかのタイミングで解決したようです。

> [image: ヘルプページのスクリーンショットです]